# How to use Vim split() when "." as pattern

Tags: string, vim, split, vi

I'm trying to write a Vim script and i need to split an input looking like:

```
"expr.expr"
```

at the `"."`

```
using split("expr.expr", ".")
```

Expected output is: `['expr' , 'expr']`
But real output is: []

changing the `"."` with something else, like a `","` works, but i need it to be a `"."`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the `.`, otherwise you're splitting on the pattern `.`, ie 'anything', resulting in an empty array.
Use `split("expr.expr", '\.')` instead.

---

You can see the difference between single and double quotes in `:help literal-string`:

```
Single quoted strings are useful for patterns, so that backslashes do not need
to be doubled.  These two commands are equivalent:
    if a =~ "\\s*"
    if a =~ '\s*'
```